# Url is getting replaced by asterisk(*) in logs of HttpLoggingInterceptor with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to see the logs of a API call in my released app through HttpLoggingInterceptor to debug for an issue but it converts the URL and some data like email etc to asterisk. eg - 200 OK *************************** (1744ms).

It is just happening in the released build that I install from google play store. If I install it locally then it works. I want to see the logs of released app because the issue I want to debug for is coming only in the released app.

There is a similar question already added but it has no answer - [HttpLoggingInterceptor url is logged as *********](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557255/httplogginginterceptor-url-is-logged-as).

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: "It is just happening in the released build that I install from google play store" -- how are you examining the logs? If you log a URL by some other means (e.g., directly via `Log.d()`), do you get the same effect? If so, then the problem is not with `HttpLoggingInterceptor`, but rather with Logcat trying to hide sensitive data.